Ubuntu 20.04 - can't start a second X session
I use Ubuntu 20.04. I can switch to tty3 (ctrl + alt + f3), log in and successfully start a second X session using the following command:
startx openbox -- :2

I would like to be able also start a second X session on tty3 from the default Xsession running on tty2. First I switch to tty3 and only log in. Then I switch back to tty2, open a gnome terminal and execute the following command:
startx openbox -- :2 vt3.
I get the following error:
Fatal server error:
(EE) xf86OpenConsole: Switching VT failed

/etc/X11/Xwrapper.config contains the following entry:
allowed_users=anybody

What I'm doing wrong ? How to start second Xsession on tty3 from the terminal running on tty2 ?
